# Questions that require a lot of discussion with the author

Tags: discussion, questions

<sub>I have a nagging feeling this may be a duplicate. My apologies if so. I could not turn up another Meta question that discusses this issue. If you know of one, I'll be happy to accept a duplicate suggestion.</sub>

There is a class of question that involves machine configuration and cannot be answered without a lot of additional details from the user. For example:

[Python and Oracle DB - "Error DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52152943/1394393)

This question is going to require *a lot* of back and forth trying to dig into exactly what binaries the application is finding (if any) and then trying to give the user some way to fix it and ensure the right ones are being found. In short, I don't think this is an appropriate question for SO because it is never going to be self contained enough to give a definitive answer for many readers. The only possible answer I could envision is some sort of community wiki answer where new possible causes and their resolution get added as they are discovered; in other words, a list of things to try.

Is closing the right option for these? What reason would be appropriate if so? Too Broad?

Comment: How do people at Server Fault and Super User handle these sort of questions? I have a feeling it's a much more common problem on those sites (especially Server Fault).

Comment: How about the "must contain an MCVE" close reason?  If you can't reproduce it on your own machine, it's not verifiable.

Comment: Seems to me that the point in such a case is the approach(es) that the questioner could be taking to resolve their own problem, and that documenting such approach(es) as answers would potentially be very useful to others.

Comment: @MandyShaw The steps are markedly dependent on the user's particular machine and usage. You have to check what's on `PATH`, which is a first step, but then you need to dig into whether their own software (or any other, like what the user mentions supposedly works) uses some modified `PATH` or finds the binaries using some other mechanism. Sometimes it involves the fact they're somehow running software under a different set of environment variables. There's too many possibilities. I can't think of a time when diagnosing something like this was straightforward.

Comment: @MandyShaw Of note here is that Power BI is .NET. It could be that the only reason it's working is because it's explicitly *not* using `PATH` directly. .NET can call out to the OS and tell it to load native binaries based on their path, without consideration for the `PATH` variable, if some piece of code does so explicitly, which I have some evidence that Oracle client does in some cases. The real answer boils down to, "understand how binaries are found and figure out where the app is finding them, then change *something* to make those load steps find the right binary before the wrong one."

Answer (score 7):

If the OP has not provided all the necessary information, vote to close the question as Unclear what you are asking,  and move on. This is not a help desk.

Comment: There's a bit of a catch 22 to consider. If they knew what information is needed, they probably wouldn't be having the problem.

Comment: @jpmc26 it still makes it a poor question.

Comment: @Cœur Of course, which is why I'm inclined to close it. But I mention it because it's an important distinction from the situation where the OP obviously has the information and just failed to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions which do require a workflow-style chart to comprehensively answer. Because there are just *too many dimensions* to reasonably cover each and every scenario separately. This class of question is indeed very specific and providing a solution to fit one set-up may not be helpful to anyone else.

However, I would use judgement here. If **you** find it interesting, answer it. Chances are, if *nobody* finds it interesting, nobody will also find it helpful.

In many cases, it's unreasonable to expect OP to know *every single factor* which can affect their environment. If they did, they wouldn't be asking the question. Again, use judgement. If you find the question interesting enough, you can **comment** asking for additional details. But if you aren't able to extract everything you need in one or two comments, you are unlikely to maintain your interest.

Regarding closure, I generally vote to close if I'm sure the question is severely lacking in inputs, unclear or too broad. Leaving out one tiny piece of information, which can be easily extracted, is unlikely to bother most of us. Leaving out half the inputs is another matter.

Comment: A question leaving out one tiny **but critical** piece of information is still reason enough to close it. Whether it's one tiny bit or a whole bunch of it, the asker still needs to provide the missing input and, until they do, the question is not answerable. Askers often don't respond to comments, so it doesn't matter how much information is missing.

Comment: @Dukeling, The point is how does OP know it's critical if you VTC without a comment (general recommendation). Requires judgement IMO. You could robo-review, but then you'd be out of close votes in approximately 4 minutes :)

Comment: I didn't say vote-to-close without commenting. I often do both. They are not mutually exclusive. If the close reason doesn't give enough information for OP to figure out how to fix their question, also adding a comment would make sense.

Comment: @Dukeling, Fair point, I've updated my wording to be specific to what I do. I like to take a view on OP. If OP has *demonstrated* an effort and is missing something extractable, I am more confident they'll respond to comments. You can't put that in a rule book, though, so be it.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the case I'm trying to describe is not a matter of "one tiny piece of information" missing. It's a matter of most likely not being able to answer without an interactive debugging session or getting lucky on a wild guess.